# How to exclude the changelogs of pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

The job is using pipeline script from repo, is there any way to exclude the changelogs of repo of pipeline script?

[image: jenkins job configure]

Comment: What changelogs do you mean?

Comment: I mean the SCM storing the pipeline scripts. The repo is shown in above screenshot.